# What was a cistern to the Babylonians?

Tags: construction, ancient-babylon

I am working with Babylonian math and some word problems mention an object called a cistern. I looked this up and it seems it can be any tank of water. Some are cylindrical, others rectangular, and others hemispherical.

In the first problem it says "a [rectangular] cistern" so that solves that but in the other it just says a cistern. Should I be assuming a cylindrical shape? I'm not sure what a standard cistern was to the Babylonians.

Comment: Here is an article on the matter, i am not sure how scholarly it is though - http://www.bible-history.com/biblestudy/cisterns.html

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary describes a *cistern* as "an artificial reservoir for the storage of water; especially a watertight tank..." The word has been used in English since the 14th century, coming almost certainly from Norman French. Originally from the Latin *cisterna*. *Etymology:  < Old French cisterne (modern citerne, compare Spanish and Italian citerna, Provençal cisterna) < Latin cisterna a subterraneous reservoir, cistern, derivative of cista box, basket, etc.: compare caverna*.

Comment: Is it the same shape as the first one described? If not, ask your professor.

Comment: @AaronBrick That addresses the OP's situation, but does not answer the question, which is valid.

Comment: Not babylon but some great ancient cistern photos here: https://ancientwatertechnologies.com/2014/03/24/ancient-water-technologies-of-the-nabataeans/

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, let me see if I can clear some things up. @AaronBrick I dont think its the same since they specified rectangular in the first question but it is not specified in this problem. Also this paper is for my history class but I chose the topic so the teacher is not aware. The problem involves measuring a cross section area of the cistern which is hard to do unless it's a defined shape.

Comment: When you say "babylonian math" does that mean base-60? Also if you look the photos I linked to above there were a number of cisterns that appeared to be rectangular, again, not Babylonian tho.  I would think if you were to make a cistern out of clay they might be cylindrical but if you were to carve from rock they might be rectilinear.  If they are naturally occurring forms good luck describing mathematically!  This is all layman speculation tho.

Comment: Well yes, base-60 in part but also their Algebra. In the first example the translator puts "a (rectangular) cistern" with rectangular in parenthesis but in the second he just puts "a cistern". Maybe my best bet is to assume he meant rectangular for the second one also.

Comment: @TheOneBobby That is actually a good idea. The translator could be indicating on the first "By the way, cisterns are rectangular", and then on the rest you are just supposed to assume that is still the case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Babylonian/Iranian Cisterns have not Fundamentally Changed across the Millenia**

A cistern (Persian: āb-anbār) was intended as a large, waterproof reservoir which also allows ventilation and access. The site was chosen as an optimal location to maximize the collection of underground moisture and/or rainwater. The excavation was lined with oven-fired brick set into a sand and clay mixture. It was then covered with a layer (about 3 cm) of waterproof mortar (sārūǰ). Larger cisterns were often lined with an additional double layer of bricks, covered with another layer of sārūǰ of slightly different composition, and finished with a hard plaster coat. The cistern was covered to prevent evaporation and protect the water supply from contamination.

Babylon existed in what is modern day Iran, so Iranian cisterns and Iranian archaeological sites are referenced here. The early history of covered cisterns in Iran has not been studied, although it is possible that a major elaboration of construction techniques may have taken place during the Parthiann and Sasanian periods, when water management constructions (dams, weirs, qanāts) were built extensively.

The above facts are paraphrased from the Encyclopaedia Iranica. Read the full article at http://www.iranicaonline.org/articles/ab-anbar-i-history

As stated in the OP, the cisterns' water volume could take the shape of a rectangular cuboid (like a rectangular tank), a cylinder (like a traditional water well), or other various shapes. The volume of a cistern constructed on a natural aquifer (cave reservoir) would be difficult to calculate. I am not aware of any illustrations/photos of spherical cisterns.